# Using a single cell with comma separated tags to tag a column of products

Tags: google-sheets

**Cell E1** contents has **product tags**:

> Sets,Cuff,Bra,Panty,**Garterbelt**,Costume,Blouse,Skirt,Pantyhose,Corset,Headwear,Lace,Crotchless,Thong,Negligee,French Maid,Nurse,Trunk,Jock,Brief,Boxer,Athletic,Mesh,Fishnet,Fencenet,Lowrise,Micro,G String,Thigh Highs,**Suspender**,Bow,Boyshort,Babydoll;Teddy,Lace,Tube Dress,Boob Tube,Chemise,Glitter,Leopard,Satin,Halter,Eyemask,Ruffle,Kimono,Schoolgirl,Bodysuit,Camisole,Cami,Bodystocking,Bustier,Gloves,Tap Shorts,Shiny,Split Crotch,Ribbon,Open Crotch,Stretch,Fingerless,Leather

**Column D2:D** has all the lingerie **product titles** like "Black **Garterbelt** and **Suspender**"

So the idea is to print in column **E2:E** comma separated tags that are in the product tile from **column D**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a formula that does this: the entry for E2 is shown but it can be dragged down.

```
=join(",", filter(split(E$1,","), regexmatch(D2, "(?i)\b" & split(E$1,",") & "\b")))
```

Explanation:

- `split(E$1,",")` split the set of tags into an array
  & `"(?i)\b" & split(E$1,",") & "\b"` turns each tag into a [regular expression](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) which means: match this string as a whole, case-insensitive.
- `regexmatch` records True if the product name matched the tag, and False if no match.
- `filter`  filters the array of tags according to the output of `regexmatch`
- `join` joins the filtered array into a comma-separated string.

Comment: Mr Human... this is EXACTLY the magic sauce!! Thank you sir...